# How to implement multitenancy with one Keycloak realm per tenant in go

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, keycloak, multi-tenant

Currently I am trying to implement multitenancy in an OAuth2 secured application by using one Keycloak realm for each tenant. I am creating a prototype in Go but am not really bound to the language and could switch to Node.js or Java if I needed to. I figure that my following question would hold true if I switched language though.

At first, implementing multitenancy seemed pretty straight forward to me:

- For each tenant, create a realm with the needed client configuration for my backend application.
- The backend receives a request with the URL `tenant-1.my-app.com`. Parse that URL to retrieve the tenant to be used for authentication.
- Connect to the OAuth2 provider (Keycloak in this case) and verify the request token.

Following a guide, I use [golang.org/x/oauth2](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2) and [github.com/coreos/go-oidc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/coreos/go-oidc). This is how I setup the OAuth 2 connection for a single realm:

```golang
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(context.Background(), "http://keycloak.docker.localhost/auth/realms/tenant-1")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

oauth2Config := oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     "my-app",
    ClientSecret: "my-app-secret",
    RedirectURL:  "http://tenant-1.my-app.com/auth-callback",
    Endpoint: provider.Endpoint(),
    Scopes: []string{oidc.ScopeOpenID, "profile", "email"},
}
state := "somestate"

verifier := provider.Verifier(&oidc.Config{
    ClientID: "my-app",
})

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tenant, err := getTenantFromRequest(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Received request for tenant %s\n", tenant)

    // Check if auth is present
    rawAccessToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
    if rawAccessToken == "" {
        log.Println("No Auth present, redirecting to auth code url...")
        http.Redirect(w, r, oauth2Config.AuthCodeURL(state), http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    // Check if auth is valid
    parts := strings.Split(rawAccessToken, " ")
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        return
    }
    _, err = verifier.Verify(context.Background(), parts[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error during auth verification (%s), redirecting to auth code url...\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, oauth2Config.AuthCodeURL(state), http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    // Authentication okay

    w.WriteHeader(200)
})

log.Printf("Starting server (%s)...\n", proxyConfig.Url)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(proxyConfig.Url, nil))
```

This works fine, but now comes the next step, adding multitenancy. IMO it seems like I would need to create one [`oidc.Provider`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2.2.1+incompatible#Provider) for every tenant, because the realm endpoint (`http://keycloak.docker.localhost/auth/realms/tenant-1`) needs to be set on in the Provider struct.

I am unsure if this is the correct way to approach this situation. I guess I would add a cache for `oidc.Provider` instances to avoid creating instances on *every* request. But is creating one

Comment: I am not sure I understood your problem correctly, specially the part of "to create one oidc.Provider ". I have a similar setup, I did not had to create any oidc.Provider

Comment: `oidc.NewProvider(context.Background(), "http://keycloak.docker.localhost/auth/realms/tenant-1")` creates a new provider. This one is needed to authenticate users that have logged in for tenant-1. May I ask why you don't use any provider instance at all?

Comment: Sure, maybe is not exactly the same, I have the Keycloak Operator that reads some custom resources to create the first realm, clients and so on. The other realms I create via scripts that use the Keycloak Admin API and that is basically it

Comment: And how does your application validate each incoming request against the correct realm endpoint?

Comment: Depends in my use case all the other realms are basically LDAPs and stuff like that. So when a user log ins into the app it gets redirected to keycloak which in turn does brokering with all the other realms, then the user explicitly selects which realm to authenticate against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this hasn't been fully used in production, here is how I prototyped a solution that I will probably end up using:

**I assume that there must be a single `oidc.Provider` for every keycloak realm.**

Therefore there will also always be one `oidc.IDTokenVerifier` for every realm.

To manage these instances, I created this interface:

```
// A mechanism that manages oidc.Provider and IDTokenVerifierInterface instances
type OAuth2ManagerInterface interface {
    GetOAuthProviderForKeycloakRealm(ctx context.Context, tenant string) (*oidc.Provider, error)
    GetOpenIdConnectVerifierForProvider(provider *oidc.Provider) (IDTokenVerifierInterface, error)
}

// Interface created to describe the oidc.IDTokenVerifier struct.
// This was created because the oidc modules does not define its own interface
type IDTokenVerifierInterface interface {
    Verify(ctx context.Context, rawIDToken string) (*oidc.IDToken, error)
}
```

Then this is the struct that will implement the manager interface:

```
type OAuth2Manager struct {
    ProviderUrl string
    ClientId    string

    // Maps keycloak provider urls onto oidc.Provider instances
    // Used internally to avoid creating a new provider on each request
    providers map[string]*oidc.Provider

    // Lock to be used when accessing OAuth2Manager.providers
    providerLock sync.Mutex

    // Maps oidc.Provider instances onto oidc.IDTokenVerifier instances
    // Used internally to avoid creating a new verifier on each request
    verifiers map[*oidc.Provider]*oidc.IDTokenVerifier

    // Lock to be used when accessing OAuth2Manager.verifiers
    verifierLock sync.Mutex
}
```

Along with the functions that actually implement the interface:

```
func (manager *OAuth2Manager) GetProviderUrlForRealm(realm string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", manager.ProviderUrl, realm)
}

func (manager *OAuth2Manager) GetOAuthProviderForKeycloakRealm(ctx context.Context, tenant string) (*oidc.Provider, error) {
    providerUrl := manager.GetProviderUrlForRealm(tenant)

    // Check if already exists ...
    manager.providerLock.Lock()
    if provider, alreadyExists := manager.providers[providerUrl]; alreadyExists {
        manager.providerLock.Unlock()
        return provider, nil
    }

    // ... create new instance if not
    provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, providerUrl)

    if err != nil {
        manager.providerLock.Unlock()
        return nil, err
    }

    manager.providers[providerUrl] = provider
    manager.providerLock.Unlock()

    log.Printf("Created new provider for provider url %s\n", providerUrl)

    return provider, nil
}

func (manager *OAuth2Manager) GetOpenIdConnectVerifierForProvider(provider *oidc.Provider) (IDTokenVerifierInterface, error) {
    // Check if already exists ...
    manager.verifierLock.Lock()
    if verifier, alreadyExists := manager.verifiers[provider]; alreadyExists {
        manager.verifierLock.Unlock()
        return verifier, nil
    }

    // ... create new instance if not
    oidcConfig := &oidc.Config{
        ClientID: manager.ClientId,
    }

    verifier := provider.Verifier(oidcConfig)

    manager.verifiers[provider] = verifier
    manager.verifierLock.Unlock()

    log.Printf("Created new verifier for OAuth endpoint %v\n", provider.Endpoint())

    return verifier, nil
}
```

It is important to use `sync.Mutex` locks if the providers are accessed concurrently.